# Custom Application icon for LabVIEW application in Control Panel after installation

Tags: labview

Please refer to the image I attached. You can see that the LabVIEW application has a default icon.

How can we add a custom icon (like a Logo) for the LabVIEW Application under the list of programs in the Control Panel?

**The application icon shows fine on the  desktop shortcut, but not in the Add / Remove Programs in the control panel.**

Can anyone suggest a way to change the icon automatically after installation is done?

Here is my Control Panel Picture
[image]

Comment: I think, this is rather a MS-registry question. I assume, that it is done in the registry, so you have to link to the icon here somewhere. It shouldn't be a problem to add registry keys via installer or on first run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to acheive the above goal, You need to use custom ico files.

Use GIMP to create Icon files.

Your Icon must contain 16x16 Layer. Only then it will replace the native windows application logo.

After this, Follow the steps:

1. Build the Exe and Installer and install the application in your PC.
2. Now, Go to Installer directory. [You'll see Setup.ini file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACVmS.png)
3. Open the File and [look for line which has "[install.msi]"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCA7b.png)
4. [Copy the ProductId value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSSOQ.png)
5. Open windows registry with Admin Rights and go to the following directory: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
6. Search for the ProductId. [You will get these details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUnbU.png)
7. [Create a New String Value named "DisplayIcon"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGO7o.png).
8. Modify the value and the data value should be your [application path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnVlt.png) where it's or it will be installed.
9. Close the Registry Window. Go to Control Panel -> Programs & Features. [The application Icon must have been updated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5axBz.png)
10. The same can be automated using a batch command.

    REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Product ID" /v "DisplayIcon" /t REG_SZ /d "Application Path"
11. This batch file can be linked with the [LabVIEW application Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnOEG.png).

**Note:** Since the productId changes every time you build the installer, You may need to add some extra logic for fetching the productId from the setup.ini file in the batch file.

Comment: I am using the custom ico file while building the installer. And it displays fine for the Desktop shortcut. The problem is only under the programs and features in the Control Panel.

Comment: Open your ico on GIMP and check the layers! It should have a layer of 16x16 image! Otherwise it will not work as you expect! I faced the same issue. This method resolved my issue :)

Comment: Okay. I will give it a try. :)

Comment: Did you try the above method?

Comment: Yes. But there was no change. Still the icon is not displayed in the control panel.

Comment: Can you send your ico file?

Comment: Hi @BalaGopi, I finally figured out how it is done! Check the updated answer and let me know if you need any more help

Comment: Hi @Achuthaperumal, I will give it a try and see if it works. Thanks.